# Magento Administration Panel icons missing

Tags: magento-community, backend, administration

I've had a **Magento ver. 1.9.0.1** store up and running for a few weeks for a client.

Since the beginning of the week, the default icons have gone missing all of sudden. I originally thought it might have been a browser cache issue, but I've tested it on multiple devices and different connections.

I've attached some pictures of the problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTtBK.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GreE7.jpg

If anyone could shed any light on whats happening I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is the image url the same as your site url? Check the media base url in System - Configuration

Comment: Hi @mbalparda, there, its the same as its always been, both secure ({{secure_base_url}}media/) and unsecure ({{unsecure_base_url}}media/) look fine.

Comment: check image is exit in /skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/ folder

Comment: @AmitBera All of the images are there, and thanks for that, its a good path worth noting for future!

Comment: Check file permissionof this folder

Comment: what would be the default permissions?

Comment: /public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default and /public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images - 755

Comment: Would it be worth my time clearing /var/cache and /var/session?

Comment: *shameless bump* The problem is now affecting the wysiwyg editor on the back end of the site. This now means staff without html knowledge cannot style product text and it looks very unprofessional. I am really desperate now, I need this fixing but I dont know whats causing it! :(

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!**
Ive fixed this now, it turned out to be Hot Link Protection on the server. So hopefully this may be useful for someone in the future.

Thanks for the help provided by community.